# Codeigniter Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS on line 1

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter controller that works perfectly on a wamp and ubuntu-lamp server. However after hosting the site I get this error

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS in /home/u885964134/public_html/gbu_helpdesk/application/controllers/Show_ticket.php on line 1
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Parsing Error
Message: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS
Filename: controllers/Show_ticket.php
Line Number: 1
```

The other controllers work fine and the T_CLASS is no where in my controller(or anywhere in my code)

The issue may be related to line endings or something else.
And for reference this my code (it works perfect on wamp, ubuntu-lamp)

```
<?php
/* 
 * Copyright (C) 2015 <> - All Rights Reserved
*/
class Show_ticket extends CI_Controller
{
    function index($tick_no = '000z')
    {
        if($tick_no == '000z')     redirect ("all_tickets");
        if ($this->session->userdata('loggedin') != 1) 
        {//Checking for authentication
            redirect('/login');
        }
        $this->session->set_userdata('tick_no',$tick_no) ;
        $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mod_note', 'Moderators Note', 'required');

        $this->load->view('common/header');
        //$this->load->view('Load_ticket');
        if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
                $this->load->view('Load_ticket');
        }
        else 
        {
             $m_note =   $this->input->post('mod_note');
             $action = "<b>".$this->session->userdata('username') . "</b> posted:<br>" . $m_note;
             $etc_action =   $this->input->post('etc_action');
             if($etc_action!='none')
             {
                 $this->session->set_userdata('yo_enter_log',1);
                 $this->session->set_userdata('add_log',$action);
                 redirect($etc_action);
             }

             $date = date('Y-m-d');
             $time  = date('H:i:s');

             $ticket_no = $tick_no;
             $action_type = "add_note";
             $this->db->query("INSERT INTO problem_logs (ticket_no,date,time,action_type,action) VALUES('$ticket_no','$date','$time','$action_type','$action')");


             redirect('/Show_ticket/index/'.$tick_no);
        }
        $this->load->view('common/footer');
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe open up the file in vi and see if there are some weird end of line characters happening that your editor isnt showing like ^m.  Also, worth comparing each machines configurations.  The big thing thats jumps out on different machines the most for me is short open tags being disabled on one but not the other.

Comment: better delete(rename) the file.and create new file with the same. type few code and check if it works and copy code. I think there are some wired charter beginning of your file.

Comment: I tried both but its not working, seems issue with the host, but I cant get where t_class is coming from. Only one thing is working that is if I call controller without any parameter it is redirecting back like it was supposed to.